# FileReader images upload

Tags: html, filereader

[jsfiddle.net link to code](http://jsfiddle.net/dasmus/sXkhf/embedded/result/) problem is when you chose multiple image files, it load all images to browser, draws all divs, but only shows one image. It should give every div its own image.

This seems to be the trouble maker code part:

```
        $('#import').change( function(event){
        namelist = new Array;
        var files = event.target.files;
        for(i=0;i<event.target.files.length; i++){
                pictures = files[i];
                image = new Image();
                image.id = i;
                image.file = pictures;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(evt){
                    image.src = evt.target.result;
                }
                namelist.push({sourceimage: image, id:i});
                reader.readAsDataURL(pictures);
            }
            drawDivs();
        });
```

Comment: issue is with this line of code 
reader.onload = function(evt){
                    image.src = evt.target.result;
                }
it will be executed in actual reading, till that image will have no data and image object will point to last image

Comment: kk, closure fixed it, dunno how i did closure wrong befor, thanks for commenting. made me try agen :)

Answer (score 0):

```
reader.onload = (function(image){
                        return function(evt){
                            image.src = evt.target.result;
                        };
                    })(image);
```

Closure fixed it